# Java implement tree search

Tags: java, search, tree

I'd like to implement and test a tree search function. I'm using the DefaultTreeModel of javax.swing. I operato on my own defined Employee objects as the tree data. I tried to get the following to work:

```
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode search(int id, DefaultMutableTreeNode node){
    if(node != null){
        Employee emp = (Employee) node.getUserObject();
        if(emp.getId() == id){
           return node;
        } else {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode foundNode = search(id, node.getPreviousSibling());
            if(foundNode == null) {
                foundNode = search(id, node.getNextSibling());
            }

            return foundNode;
         }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

but it can only find the element which is among one parent's siblings. And like to find it in entire tree, from root to leaves. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could navigate to the root of the tree first in a different method, then call your current recursive method.

```
private DefaultMutableTreeNode search(int id, DefaultMutableTreeNode node){
    if(node == null){
        return null;
    }
    node = node.getRoot(); //Turns out that this class has a getRoot() method.
    return searchInternal(id,node); //Then does a depth-first search from the root node.
}

private DefaultMutableTreeNode searchInternal(int id, DefaultMutableTreeNode node){
    if(node == null){ //I also switched this around, for good practice.
        return null;
    }
    Employee emp = (Employee) node.getUserObject();
    if(emp.getId() == id){ //Found it!
        return node;
    }
    DefaultMutableTreeNode foundNode = searchInternal(id, node.getPreviousSibling());
    if(foundNode == null) {
        foundNode = search(id, node.getNextSibling());
    }

    return foundNode;
}
```

In general, recursive methods tend to run a bit slower in Java, and they are prone to stack overflowing. It's usually better to use a custom stack for depth-first search, and this doesn't require you to make a different method. Recursive methods might make the code more readable in some cases.

What also works, in this case:

```
private DefaultMutableTreeNode search(int id, DefaultMutableTreeNode node){
    if(node == null){
        return null;
    }
    Enumeration enumeration = node.getRoot().depthFirstEnumeration(); //Enumerate over all nodes in the tree.
    while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()){
        DefaultMutableTreeNode next = enumeration.next();
        if(((Employee)next.getUserObject()).getId() == id){ //Found it!
            return next;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Turns out that depth-first searching is already implemented by Swing. This is a post-order enumeration though. See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html), there are also methods for the other types of traversals.